# UILabel not rendering with correct font size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

> UIScrollView (Paged) --> UICollectionView

I have a UIScrollView with paging. Each page of the UIScrollView has a UICollectionView. Each collection view cell has different font size . So I set the font size for each collection view cell dynamically based on its type.

Now I set the font size inside the  **cellForitemAtIndexPath** of the UICollectionView Delegate like this.

minFontSize = [self findFontSizeforLabel:cell.productTitle];

Now I set the font text and size like this,

```
cell.productTitle.text = [product.title uppercaseString];
[cell.productTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PFBagueSansPro-Black" size:minFontSize]];
NSLog(@"Product Title %@ set at font size %.2f and current minFontSize is %.2f",cell.productTitle.text,cell.productTitle.font.pointSize,minFontSize);
```

The log shows that the title is set with the correct font size, but on screen its still rendering the default font size set in the storyboard.

I have two scenarios where this works well,

When the app loads the colelctionview is hidden from user. When user clicks a button the data is loaded on each page.

Scenario 1 : The dynamically calculated font is properly set on the first collection view cells. Not on others. All other collection view cells are showing font sizes set from Storyboard.

Scenario 2: Start app, Click button to display collection view cells. Now as in scenario 1 only the first Collection view sets the fonts correctly. Now I click the button again to remove collection view. Now I click the button for last time to reveal the collection view. This time all the collection view cells display correct font sizes.

I am not sure why i see this behaviour.

This is how I load the collection view to the ScrollView. This is called inside a loop( As I mentioned each page of scrollview has a collection view)

```
if(view.itemsViewController == nil){
        view.itemsViewController = [[PackageItemsViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        [view.productsColectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProductCell" bundle:[ResourceBundle bundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Product Cell"];
        view.itemsViewController.jPackage = package;
        view.productsColectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        view.productsColectionView.dataSource = view.itemsViewController;
        view.productsColectionView.delegate = view.itemsViewController;
        view.itemsViewController.collectionView = view.productsColectionView;
        [view.itemsViewController viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Here is the code for cellForItemAtIndexPath,

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ProductCell *cell = (ProductCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Product *product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //minFontSize = [self findFontSizeforLabel:cell.productTitle];

    cell.productTitle.text = [product.title uppercaseString];
    //[cell.productTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PFBagueSansPro-Black" size:15]];
    cell.productSubTitle.text = [product.subTitle uppercaseString];
    [cell.productPrice setPrice:product.skProduct.price withLocale:product.skProduct.priceLocale];
    [cell.recommendedIcon setHidden:!product.isRecommended];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your `cellForitemAtIndexPath` method. It may be possible, that you accidentally reuse cells in several collection views.

Comment: @mschmidt Thanks. Updated question with requested code.